C++ netcore 6.0 dll issue loading into Java 8 program
I am unable to show any code as the code is on a closed network. But here is the issue.
There is a Java program running with Java 8 that I do not have the ability to change.  This program uses System.load() to load in a C++ DLL that use JNI.  The C++ dll is my software and is used to connect the Java program to my C# program.  We are updating our code from dotnet framework 4.8 to dotnet 6.0.  When I build the C++ dll CLR with target framework of 4.8 it loads just fine into the Java program.  If I change just the CLR to netcore and Target to .NET 6.0 and build it the Java program throws an error stating "Can't find dependencies".  I've used dumpbin to find the dependencies of the dll, all of which were either in the same folder or the system32 folder.  I for the sake of testing moved them all to the same folder as the C++ dll, but to no avail.  I can't get it to load.  Is there a dependency issue I'm missing (I'm hoping this is the case), or is this possibly an error due to Java 8 program not supporting a C++ dll build with netcore 6.0 (I hope this isn't the case as I can't update the Java program)?  I can't seem to find anything online with this specific issue.  I'm not sure why the C++ CLR dll works fine but the C++ netcore dll fails to load.  Any help would be appreciated.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

The error is certainly not Java 8 not supporting a C++ DLL built with .NET 6.0, it is with .NET 6.0 not producing a compatible DLL. No doubt the "Can't find dependencies" is because the symbols in the new DLL are different. You need to figure out what switches to pass to .NET 6.0 to get it to produce a usable DLL.

When you dump the two DLLs, what do the symbols look like? What else is different between the two libraries? It is those differences you need to focus on.

Thank you for the info. I'll look into that Tuesday when I get back to work.

When I ran dumpbin.exe /SYMBOLS I got the following: DLL CLR: 2000 .data, 1000 .nep, 1000 .pdata, 1A00 .rdata, 1000 .rsrc, 8000 .text.  The DLL NetCore had the same except for 1D00 .rdata, B000 .text.  Is this what you were asking about?

I found that it isn't the dll. It's something missing on the computer. It works fine on one computer but not the other, even with the dotnet runtime installed. There is some dependency missing that is outside the project.
